# Element Manager needs help making specific elements top

Tags: c++, user-interface, z-order

I am trying to make an element system for my GUI, but I have a problem!

I am calling `CBaseElement::MakeTop()` every time a mouseclick has been detected inside a window

```
void CBaseElement::MakeTop()
{
    int nSize = g_pElementList.size();

    for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < nSize; iIndex++)
    {
        CBaseElement* pNode = g_pElementList[iIndex];
        if (pNode == this)
        {
            g_pElementList.erase(g_pElementList.begin() + iIndex);
            g_pElementList.push_back(this);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I let the cursor element be the last to be rendered and the tooltip to be second?
I have did this method:

```
void CBaseElement::MakeTop()
{
    int nSize = g_pElementList.size();

    for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < nSize; iIndex++)
    {
        CBaseElement* pNode = g_pElementList[iIndex];
        if (pNode == this)
        {
            g_pElementList.erase(g_pElementList.begin() + iIndex);
            g_pElementList.push_back(this);

            for (int iIndex2 = 0; iIndex2 < nSize; iIndex2++)
            {
                CBaseElement* pNode2 = g_pElementList[iIndex2];
                if (pNode2->GetType() == ET_TOOLTIP || pNode2->GetType() == ET_CURSOR)
                {
                    g_pElementList.erase(g_pElementList.begin() + iIndex2);
                    g_pElementList.push_back(pNode2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need a better way of doing this.